# How do I render HTML from the Viewbag using MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, viewbag

I need to pass a form element into an MVC4 view using ViewBag. The Viewbag is a list of 1 or more records for each user. The issue is nothing is being passed.

controller

```
// grab all records for user id 26000.
    var qry = db.users.Where(m => m.user_id == "26000").ToList();
    foreach (var myBag in qry)
    { 
     // place all the items in the Viewbag.
    ViewBag.myItems = "<input type='text' name=@ViewBag.myBag value=@ViewBag.myBag>";
    }
```

view

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
     {
     foreach (var item in ViewBag.myBag)
     {
        <label for="@item">@item</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="@item" value="@item"/>
     }    

    <input id='btnSubmit' type="submit" value='submit' /> 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller (the query should really be in your Model).

```
ViewBag.myItems = db.users.Where(m => m.user_id == "26000").ToList();
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
{
    foreach (var item in ViewBag.myItems)
    {
        <input type="text" name="@item.user_id" value="@item.user_name">
    }
    <input id='btnSubmit' type="submit" value='submit' /> 
}
```